# Is there any way to get the direct hexadecimal value in bytes instead of getting string value?

Tags: python-3.x, byte

In python3.5 I need to convert the string to IPFIX supported field value for UDP packet. While I am sending string bytes as UDP packet I am unable to recover the string data again. In Wireshark, it says that "Malformed data".

I found that IPFIX supports only the "ASCII" for strings. So I have converted ASCII value to hex and then converted into bytes. But while converting hex("**4B**") to byte. I am not getting my hex value in bytes instead of I am getting the string in bytes("**K**").

I have tried the following in the python console. I need exact byte what I have entered. But it seems like b'\x4B' instead of '\x4B' I am getting 'K'. I am using python3.5

> b'\x4B'
>
> b'K'

Code:  "K".encode("ascii")

Actual OP: b'K'

Expected OP: b'\x4B'

Comment: I have added that atlast in the question

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this:

#### 1. The `hex` method (python 3.5 and up)

```
>>> 'K'.encode('ascii').hex()
'4b'  # type str
```

#### 2. Using `binascii`

```
>>> binascii.hexlify('K'.encode('ascii'))
b'4b'  # type bytes
```

#### 3. Using `str.format`

```
>>> ''.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in 'K'.encode('ascii'))
'4b'  # type str
```

#### 4. Using `format`

```
>>> ''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in 'K'.encode('ascii'))
'4b'  # type str
```

**Note:** Methods using `format` are not very performance efficient.

If you really care about the `\x` you will have to use `format`, eg:

```
>>> print(''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(x) for x in 'K'.encode('ascii')))
\x4b
>>> print(''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(x) for x in 'KK'.encode('ascii')))
\x4b\x4b
```

If you care about uppercase then you can use `X` instead of `x`, eg:

```
>>> ''.join('{:02X}'.format(x) for x in 'K'.encode('ascii'))
'4B'
>>> ''.join(format(x, '02X') for x in 'K'.encode('ascii'))
'4B'
```

Uppercase and with `\x`:

```
>>> print(''.join('\\x{:02X}'.format(x) for x in 'Hello'.encode('ascii')))
\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F
```

If you want `bytes` instead of `str` then just encode the output to `ascii` again:

```
>>> print(''.join('\\x{:02X}'.format(x) for x in 'Hello'.encode('ascii')).encode('ascii'))
b'\\x48\\x65\\x6C\\x6C\\x6F'
```

Comment: b'\\x48\\x65\\x6C\\x6C\\x6F' 

I need something like this

b'\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F'

Comment: Look at the last example, it is actually just one \, but it shows two \\ because backslash is an escape character so it needs to to escaped

Comment: Yes I need only "\" in the end result

Comment: try something like this `r'abc\d'.encode('ascii')`  in your python console, you will see that even with raw string single backslash will become two after getting encoded. Or even try `b'abc\d'`, even you write a single backslash it will be two in output

Comment: Also you should not add `\x` to your hex, because after that it's no longer a valid hexadecimal. `\x` is just for representation. You cannot go back to `Hello` from `\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F` you will need `48656C6C6F` to be able to decode it back to `Hello`. Also I think it's more common to prefix hexadecimal with `0x` not `\x`, so it's usually `0x48656C6C6F`

Comment: hmmm do you have any suggestion to convert "string" to ipfix field which can be able to send via UDP packet.

Comment: I have no clue what ipfix is.